# Lifecycle of nested activities

Tags: android, android-activity, nested

I have some tabs and an activity group (Contacts) with several nested activities:

> Contacts Tab
>           |
> Contact Groups -> Contact List -> Edit Contact

I used [this example](http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities/) to manage walking through these nested activities. So, when I click on a Contact Group, I'm sending parameters about that group using intent and LocalActivityManager

> LocalActivityManager lam = Contacts.contacts.getLocalActivityManager();
> Window w = lam.startActivity("ContactListActivity", intent);
> View view = w.getDecorView();

But when I get back to the first activity (Contact Groups) and select another contact group from the list, ContactListActivity is starting without firing "onCreated" method - it seems that the activity started using LocalActivityManager is somehow kept alive and doesn't fire "pause", "destroy" and other events until its parent ActivityGroup experiences that event.

I tried using `getLocalActivityManager().destroyActivity(activityId, false);` but then, when I would click contact group again, this: `lam.startActivity("ctsActivity", intent);` would return null...

Help! How can I use nested activities with normal activity lifecycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer!
I forgot to add "FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP" to the intent that was passed from one activity to the other... Wasted 5 hours of my life on that :)